# How to add an view on top on activity layout dynamically which automatically shifted the old view down

Tags: android-layout

I am working on an App in which I have an icon on Action Bar.When I click on this Action Bar icon then an **EditText** should come on the top of layout(below Action Bar) and all of the other data on layout should shif down.I am using **Relative Layout**.

I know how we can dynamically add view in relative layout.But here I have to add item on top on layout, while there is also some view on top before clicking the icon.

Comment: If you need other info then please tell me

Comment: i think you can place edittext in top and then set visibility as gone and when you click on icon you set visibility as visible

Comment: I have dynamically add EditText on top of activity layout and set the other component below this view.This work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below if it works for you, this is what you'll need as per my understanding of your question.

```
    EditText et = new EditText(this);
    empty.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    et.setText("Dynamic EditText!");
    et.setMinLines(1);
    et.setMaxLines(3);
    relativelayout.addView(et);

 // assuming you already have your relative layout and the rest declared.
```